# We should probably have this option too while recommending deletion

Tags: feature-request

A post popped up in my **low quality postbox** today, which was, I am not entirely sure but feels like was, flagged. I get the flagger's point. But the issue was that the answer posted to the question was a random paragraph taken from I don't know where and pasted in there. I believe the answerer was testing the site. Great!

I have personally seen people posting a comment telling such people exactly the words I have written in the last two sentences of the previous paragraph. Well it is one approach. But wouldn't it be more handy if we had an option to delete the answerer's post when it has been flagged by one or more people.

What happens is when we click the `delete` button as a recommended action while reviewing the task, the following dialog box appears on the screen.

[image: add a comment for the author]

The problem here is, there is no option stating something like **Not an answer - "This is no answer at all. You were trying to test the website for its features and functionalities, which you now have. Congratulations! Post your [first question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), or answer an [existing one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions) (correctly this time)."**

Now, I don't know exactly how the delete messages appear to the authors, since I never had my post deleted by someone else. But I am assuming the messages written inside the double quotes are what appears on their screen. Hence my suggestion would likely be a handy addition other than having to choose other not-so-fitting options, or worse, the first one.

---

I don't know if this issue is already addressed or not, because I didn't get something related when I typed in certain keywords. I hope someone notices this.

Comment: You could always flag it for moderator attention. They have a whole range of magical powers.

Comment: I disagree that we want to congratulate people for posting random text to “test” the site. I think we want to discourage that sort of thing. I can’t recall that I’ve ever seen a useful follow up post from an account that blatantly ignored all of the guidance on the screen and posted random text. I have seen people who have posted a question as an answer repost as a question after a comment from the low quality queue.

Comment: @ColleenV I am not sure about the statistics of such people never posting again. Though, I do agree about the situation of a question posted as an answer to another totally unrelated question. Might be we can strip that part of congratulating them and replace it with something more warning like.

Answer (score 1):

The canned comments aren't meant to cover every single reason for recommending to delete a post. There are simply too many reasons.

You can either leave a comment before deciding on a review action (after a few reviews, you'll remember upfront which ones are available), or complete the review and then use the back button to add a comment. As a bonus, you'll see what other reviewers' decisions were.

Comment: I agree about that bit of being too many reasons. I didn't quite understand that second suggestion. I must work around the reviews a bit more to know everything.